# Request current route including query strings?

Tags: python, pyramid

I've been looking in the Pyramid API and haven't been able to find a method that allows me to extract the url in the user's address bar, specifically including the query strings. Is there a method I keep skimming across?

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/dev/api/request.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you just want `request.url` which is whatever the user typed in the address bar.

`request.GET` is a dictionary of key/values in the query string.

`request.POST` is a dictionary of key/values in the request body.

`request.params` is a dictionary of the combination of both.

This might be better explained in the webob documentation, which is effectively what Pyramid is using for its request and response objects.

http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Now one can use `request.query_string` if you only want the URL-encoded text after the `?` (ie `id=10&name=Bob`)
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/webob.html